# New XML file from another large XML file, problem with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml

I have a large XML file which excerpt I will give here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mlm:bagMutaties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ml="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/mutatielevering-generiek/1.0" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
xmlns:selecties-extract="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/extract-selecties/v20200601" 
xmlns:mlm="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/extract-deelbestand-mutaties-lvc/v20200601" 
xmlns:nen5825="www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/imbag/nen5825/v20200601" 
xmlns:KenmerkInOnderzoek="www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/imbag/kenmerkinonderzoek/v20200601" 
xmlns:DatatypenNEN3610="www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/imbag/datatypennen3610/v20200601" 
xmlns:Historie="www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/imbag/historie/v20200601" 
xmlns:Objecten="www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/imbag/objecten/v20200601" 
xmlns:Objecten-ref="www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/imbag/objecten-ref/v20200601" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/extract-deelbestand-mutaties-lvc/v20200601 http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/lvbag/extract-deelbestand-mutaties-lvc/v20200601/BagvsExtractDeelbestandMutatieLvc-2.1.0.xsd">
  <mlm:bagInfo>
    <selecties-extract:Gebied-Registratief>
      <selecties-extract:Gebied-NLD />
...
```

Now I am using XmlReader / XmlWriter combination to copy all nodes + add new nodes when some conditions are met.

For the moment I want to recreate the same XML like this (not finished though):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var xml = @"F:\Test\9999MUT29032021-30032021-000002.xml";
      XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml);
      XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml");

      var currentElementName = "";
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
          case XmlNodeType.Element:
            currentElementName = reader.Name;
            writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);

            //Copy all attributes verbatim
            if (reader.HasAttributes)
              writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);

            //Handle empty elements by telling the writer to close right away
            if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
              writer.WriteEndElement();
            break;
          case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            currentElementName = "";
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            break;
          case XmlNodeType.Text:
              writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
            break;
          case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
            break;
            //Other cases. Attributes, comments etc.
        }
        writer.Flush();
      }

      reader.Close();
      writer.Close();

    }
```

The exception that I am having is at

```
writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
```

Stating that:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid name character in 'mlm:bagMutaties'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.'
```

I guess the code is not copying namespaces. So, how to copy namespaces too?

Answer (score 2):

Use `WriteStartElement` method with 3 parameters:

```
writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem for me was how to get those namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get those namespaces:

```
  XPathDocument x = new XPathDocument(reader);
  XPathNavigator foo = x.CreateNavigator();
  foo.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element);
  IDictionary<string, string> Namespaces = foo.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All);
```

As [Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/get-namespaces-from-an-xml-document-with-xpathdocument-and-linq-to-xml) described.